# Python 2.7 and anaconda2 - No such file

Tags: python, anaconda

I am a beginner in Python and anaconda2.

When I try to do a small code in notepad and run it in the anaconda command prompt it is showing as the file and directory do not exist.

[image]

Comment: Please share notebook screenshot

Comment: Are you in the right folder while running the file?

Comment: Yes i am in right folder i have checked it.

Comment: jupyter notebook will show `HOME_PATH` by default, That probably means where you are seeing `c:\users\{user}`.
So let's check. correct or not. And what about move your file to `HOME_PATH`

Comment: For me the path is c:\users\ibm\anaconda2: python first_program.py